# Invalid json error thrown when using express.bodyParser

Tags: json, curl, express

Before I add app.use(express.bodyParser()) into my code, everything works finely.

After I added it, express keep thrown me the invalid json error.What am I miss? Here's the command line I used.

```
curl -d '{"disc":"1"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080
```

Here's the log

```
Error: invalid json
    at Object.exports.error (C:\Users\123\Documents\googledrive\Google Drive\nodejs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\utils.js:60:13)
    at IncomingMessage.module.exports (C:\Users\123\Documents\googledrive\Googl
 Drive\nodejs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\j
on.js:74:71)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
    at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:2
)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1825:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:404:27)
```

Here's the code I used

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post("/",function(request,response){        

    response.send("hello");
    response.end();
});

var port = 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log("listen on "+port);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by do some simple edit on curl command.

Use "{\"disc\":\"1\"}" instead of '{"disc":"1"}'

I guess it happened as I am using japanese windows. It seem likes CURL don't recognize ' symbol in japanese windows.

Comment: I think the same is true for running curl in all versions of Windows. I just encountered the same issue running Windows Server 2008R2 using a windows native version of curl.